# Change hash before link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I have a Javascript web app which contains Adsense ads. However, when the user clicks the ad and presses the back button, the Javascript app has lost its place.

I used to change the hash value a lot, but that led to an enormous history leading the user needing to press the back button a lot of times.

One option is perhaps a cookie to store the place in the JS app.

Is it however also possible to change the hash value just before the ad redirect? In which case the user would be directed back from the ad to my URL with the hash value on it?

Or is this completely bad behaviour?

Comment: Have you tryed to change the hash on `mousedown`, which event occurs just before `click` ?

Comment: Or instead of a `cookie`, if your wish to store it, look for [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: You could use URL parameters but the user could delete them. I suggest using binding to window.onbeforeunload and set a cookie with a short experation and just check for it when users first arrive to your site

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions all. I am leaning towards a cookie or localstorage. Whether I'll go with a cookie kind of depends on the european cookie law. It would technically require a cookie request to the user, but not sure if the law is strictly enforced.